# Statistics of interacting gases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, interactions

I am doing a course on Statistical Physics and we just finished through discussions of fermions and bosons and the distribution functions of quantum gases. However, in all the cases, the system is ideal meaning no interaction. I am sure the work has already been done so could experienced people point me to what happens when we include interactions in the same cases eg Electromagnetic interaction.
Also, how do the distributions change in the presence of another non-interacting particles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be looking for more complex Equations of State for gases, which account for interactions among other things. Van der Walls is the most well known, but there are many. Sometimes using fugacity in place of pressure can correct for real gas behavior as well.

Comment: This is in general a very complex question. A substantial part of the field of condensed matter physics is attempting to answer this